# php select all bookings on and between certain dates

Tags: php, mysql, date, inner-join

I have a query that is supposed to select all bookings between dates

```
 SELECT t1.*, treatment.treatmentName, 
t2.userForename, t2.userSurname, 
t3.userForename as clientForename, t3.userSurname as clientSurname, t3.userPost as clientPost, t3.userAd1 as clientAd1,  
t4.userForename as createdForename, t4.userSurname as createdSurname 
            FROM booking t1 
            INNER JOIN treatment ON t1.idtreatment = treatment.idtreatment
            INNER JOIN user t2 ON t2.iduser = t1.idstylist
            INNER JOIN user t3 ON t3.iduser = t1.iduser
            INNER JOIN user t4 ON t4.iduser = t1.bookingCreatedBy
             WHERE 
             t1.bookingDate>=%s AND t1.bookingDate<=%s)  
             ORDER BY t1.bookingDate ASC, t1.bookingSTime ASC, t1.idtreatment ASC
```

If I pass the query a start and end date like so....

```
 SELECT t1.*, treatment.treatmentName, 
t2.userForename, t2.userSurname,
 t3.userForename as clientForename, t3.userSurname as clientSurname, t3.userPost as clientPost, t3.userAd1 as clientAd1, 
t4.userForename as createdForename, t4.userSurname as createdSurname 
 FROM booking t1 
INNER JOIN treatment ON t1.idtreatment = treatment.idtreatment 
INNER JOIN user t2 ON t2.iduser = t1.idstylist 
INNER JOIN user t3 ON t3.iduser = t1.iduser 
INNER JOIN user t4 ON t4.iduser = t1.bookingCreatedBy 
WHERE t1.bookingDate>='2017-01-01' AND t1.bookingDate<='2017-01-07' 
ORDER BY t1.bookingDate ASC, t1.bookingSTime ASC, t1.idtreatment ASC
```

it seems to be returning results outside of that range if I echo the dates of each row returned. for example I'm getting in my result set...

07/09/2016, 07/09/2016, 26/09/2016, 07/09/2016, 07/09/2016, 05/01/2017, 07/09/2016, 20/09/2016, 07/09/2016

as you can see theres only actually one thats right in my array thats returned.

Comment: Is `bookingDate` a DATE or a DATETIME column?

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is a date column

Comment: Ok so which date column are you displaying when you show these dates

Comment: @RiggsFolly you've had just solved the problem.  I am displaying the booking created date not the actual booking date.  Thank you.  I've been going over this for about 1 hour!!!!!  please submit your answer so I can accept.

Comment: Ok, its not really my best ever answer but there you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought, what date column are you displaying when you say the date are wrong?

Make sure it is `t1.bookingDate`

Comment: Yes thank you.  Obviously been looking at this far too long.  I was displaying  a completely different date field from my result set.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  Your "template" query looks has this:

```
        WHERE t1.bookingDate>=%s AND t1.bookingDate<=%s) 
-------------------------------------------------------^
```

The closing paren is a syntax error.  So, you shouldn't be getting any results.

The query that you claim to be running is:

```
WHERE t1.bookingDate>='2017-01-01' AND t1.bookingDate<='2017-01-07'
```

The closing paren has mysteriously disappeared.

For this type of problem, the first assumption is the datatypes.  However, you say that the date is really a date.  A second possibility is more clauses in the `WHERE`.  If you have an `OR`, then you will get unexpected results.  So, enclose this fully in parentheses:

```
        WHERE (t1.bookingDate >= %s AND t1.bookingDate <= %s)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to replace 
WHERE t1.bookingDate>=%s AND t1.bookingDate<=%s
to WHERE t1.bookingDate between %s and %s